# How do I tackle this combinatorics problem about married couples around a table?

Tags: combinatorics

Here is the question, [from Bogart's](http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~kpbogart/ComboNotes3-20-05.pdf) :

> A group of n married couples comes to a group discussion session where
>   they all sit around a round table. In how many ways can they sit so
>   that no person is next to his or her spouse? (Note that two people of
>   the same sex can sit next to each other.

I appreciate any tips or advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a variant of the [Menage Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9nage_problem) and a solution of that can be found in one of Bogart's articles(no surprise there) itself: http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~doyle/docs/menage/menage/menage.html

(See the solution to the Relaxed Menage Problem).

Comment: Thank You So Much - this clears it up a lot!

Comment: @Adel: You are welcome :-)